# Dar match em uma rota com "localhost:4200/teste-(parametro dinâmico)" no Angular 7

Tags: angular, regex, angular-routes

**Resumo do problema:** É uma daquelas URL's amigáveis que será enviada e dentro do parenteses virá a sigla do aeroporto da cidade, preciso que a rota seja ativada quando ela vier com esses parâmetros.

Ex: `/voos-sao-paulo(gru)` baseado nessa URL de rota `voos-` (que é o trabalho da função `matcher` que está no stackblitz) preciso fazer um request passando `sao-paulo` e `gru` (que serão extraidos da url) que é o aeroporto de guarulhos para a API. Os parâmetros da cidade e da sigla do aeroporto serão dinâmicos e terão outros como data, outros aeroportos e etc.

A função `matcher` do stackblitz funciona pois todas as URLs que virão vão obrigatoriamente começar com `voos-`.

O problema é que com o que vem dentro dos ( ) não dá match na rota e o Angular lança um erro e eu não consigo pegar o que vem na URL, se vier uma rota sem os `( )` só com `gru` a rota entra na função `matcher` e funciona como esperado.

**StackBlitz simulando o problema**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nadrke?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a8bdrn?file=src/app/hello.component.ts arrumei seu stackblitz só digita /qualquer coisa no fim da url que deve funcionar

Comment: Você quer extrair o valor do parenteses ?

Comment: @EduardoVargas não serviu

Comment: @VictorHenrique editei o post e creio ter colocado uma explicação melhor

Comment: Tenta fazer com httpInterceptors se ou com o esse parametro dinamico e chamar um serviço com os parametros como no meu stackblitz

Comment: Não da pra usar interceptor pq não vai ta no angular ainda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu `AppComponent` logo no `ngOnInit` verifique o `window.location.pathname` que é o que o angular router vai analisar para encontrar as rotas.

> Lembre-se de inserir no componente principal da sua aplicação.

```
if(window.location.pathname.includes('(') || window.location.pathname.includes(')')) {
   window.location.pathname = window.location.pathname.replace(/\(/g, '%28').replace(/\)/g, '%29');
}
```

Exemplo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p13och?file=src/app/app.component.ts

> Outra alternativa é você colocar no seu `index.html` uma tag script logo após o o fechamento da tag `app-root` o conteúdo abaixo.

```
<script> window.history.pushState("", "", window.location.pathname.replace(/\(/g, '%28').replace(/\)/g, '%29') + window.location.search); </script>
```

Exemplo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pyka24?file=src/index.html

> **NOTA:** eu não acho que essas soluções sejam elegantes, porém acredito ser a única maneira para resolver o seu problema.

Comment: funcionou valeu usei a ultima solução!